# create a series of strings in python

Tags: python, string, list, series

Does anyone know the way to create a series of strings in Python that are called consecutively ?

Like 'ABCDEF' and then first goes 'A', then 'B' then 'C' etc ? or you could call them from different point, like 'D' then 'E' then 'F' then 'A' etc

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do. As the question currently stands, it is unclear.

Comment: sorry about the confusion, i'm new to this forum...

I'm trying to see the easiest way to cycle through a series of strings (e.g. letters) with perhaps a different starting point each time. 

like if I have a string 'ABCDEF' I could get each separate string with 'A' first, 'B' second etc, but in a loop of fixed repeats. And each repeat could have a different starting point, like C, D, E, F, but always a loop of 6 strings or as much as they are originally. 

I think I made it even more confusing... !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something that enables a start point, length, and "rotates" around the end, you can use:
(Take note of the slicing, the `.index()` command and the handy `ascii_uppercase` constant)

```
from itertools import islice, cycle
from string import ascii_uppercase

def func(start='A', length=1, source=ascii_uppercase):
    src = list(source)
    idx = src.index(start)
    cyc = cycle(src[idx:] + src[:idx])
    return ''.join(islice(cyc, length))

>>> func(length=10)
'ABCDEFGHIJ'
>>> func(length=10, start='X')
'XYZABCDEFG'
>>> func()
'A'
>>> func(length=3)
'ABC'
```

Comment: I think this might work actually !

Comment: @PavAmetvic If it doesn't - you've got enough there to be able to build your own quite easily

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want here:

```
for c in "ABCDEF":
    print (c)
```

will give you 1 character at a time.  Or you could construct a list out of it:

```
print(list("ABCDEF"))
```

Strings are subscriptable:

```
a = "ABCDEF"
print (a[1]) #B
```

So you can get the individual elements that way ...

If you want to construct a string starting at element 3 that is cyclic:

```
a = "ABCDEF"
cycle = a[3:] + a[:3]
```

which can then be iterated over or subscripted as above.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```
In [3]: for i in range(len(s)+1):
   ...:     print s[i:]
   ...: 
ABCDEF
BCDEF
CDEF
DEF
EF
F
```